# Update mp3 tags by eyeD3 in Python

Tags: python, mp3, id3-tag

I want to update the Mp3 (ID3) tags in Japanese but it gives me error when i tried this code

```
tag = eyeD3.Tag()
tag.link(mp3_file_name)
tag.setVersion([2,3,0])
tag.setArtist(u'\u897f\u306f\u3058\u3081')
tag.update()
```

`tag.update()` line through this error

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(256)

How do i add Japanese name in mp3's artist tag?

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The error code states that you are using the "latin-1" codec.
Use the "--set-encoding=latin1|utf8|utf16-BE|utf16-LE" switch to use a codec that works.

Comment: Is there any function like this in `eyeD3` python lib, where i can set encoding?

Comment: @Ahsan Try adding # -\*- coding: shift_jis -\*- at the top of your script and at the top of the eyeD3 source file.

Comment: same error, and can you please explain this line, what it will do?

Comment: It looks like the problem is you cant find a coding that works. Try to fine a [coding](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) that will allow you to save the text in to a simple text file. Then use that coding like I said in my last comment.